# Use resource file in XAML file (Xamarin)

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How to use resource files in XAML (xamarin forms) like `<Label Text="MyApp.resouces.MyString" />`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a nice article [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/advanced/localization/) covering this topic. It includes lot of examples.

After you implement your TranslateExtension your code will look like this:

```
<Label x:Name="lblName" Text="{local:TranslateExtension MyString}" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Your App.axml file:

```
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Master.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <!-- Application resource dictionary -->
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <x:String x:Key="AppName">Name of app</x:String>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

And then your label:

```
<Label Text="{StaticResource AppName}"/>
```